# Change jQueryUI datepicker to monthpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Is it possible to manipulate jQueryUI's default datepicker to a monthpicker or a yearpicker? I have been going through their documentation but all I could find is `changeMonth` and `changeYear` which don't seem to do the trick. Please help. I donot want to install a third party month picker which is why I am trying this.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a default datepicker. Do you mean the jQueryUI one?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes

Comment: In that case please see the duplicate question for more information